# Using a formula with a range having a variable

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have columns with a number of rows. I also have a module that counts certain cells when conditional formatting evaluates to true within the columns.

I can use a formula such as

`=CountCFCells(A2:A201,README!$A$2)`

and I get the correct result. However, I only want to examine the first X amount of rows (not all 201) I need to have a variable for the end row. I've defined NoR = 30 using the name manager and changed my formula to

`=CountCFCells("A2:A" & NoR,README!$A$2)`

however, this returns an error. It appears that the variable is substituted into the formula, but the range is in double quotes like

```
=CountCFCells("A2:A30",README!$A$2)
```

I believe the double quotes around my range is causing the error. Does any one know a solution to this problem? Thank you

Comment: Can we see more of your code please? In VBA, what you have posted could not even be a complete line. My guess is that you forgot to enclose the entire formula in quotes and use the range.formula property.

Comment: The answers below by asongtoruin and Rory work correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I avoid INDIRECT whenever possible as it's volatile - and I suspect your function takes a bit of calculating. I'd suggest INDEX instead:

```
=CountCFCells(A2:INDEX(A:A,NoR),README!$A$2)
```

This construction is still semi-volatile (it will recalculate when you first open the workbook) but better than fully volatile.

Answer (score 2):

Is the function `CountCFCells` is expecting a range as an input, rather than a string? If so, try `INDIRECT`, like so:

```
=CountCFCells(INDIRECT("A2:A" & NoR),README!$A$2)
```

Comment: Yes, CountCFCells expects (rng As Range, C As Range). This works, Thank you